# How to build tarball of a rust application?

Tags: rust, tar, rust-cargo

I'm trying to package the application into a tarball so I found the [`cargo-tarball`](https://github.com/crate-ci/cargo-tarball) which does not like actively used and supported.

What is the common way to build tarball for a binary crate with cargo?

Comment: Could you make a custom build-script to "package" your application? Keep in mind that tarballs are really not the best way to accomplish this. You may want to make a proper package for whatever operating system you're targeting.

Comment: @tadman If by build-script you mean shell-script or so then yes, definitely. I imagine that I prepare a realease first and then put the binary (and some default config files) into the tarball... ?

Comment: I think they're referring to [cargo's build script system](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html).

Comment: Cargo build scripts are run _before_ the crate is compiled, so they can't be used to package the binary.

Comment: @Jmb so the simplest way to do this is to write a shell-script that would do all the stuff.